# fluentd vs prometheus vs elasticsearch, when to use what?

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, prometheus, fluentd, observability

When to use fluentd vs prometheus vs elasticsearch?
There seems to be overlapping between these tools interms of the feature set they provide but I have seen projects using all these 3 tools in unison. Quite confusion why these 3 tools has to be in the same solution. Does these 3 tools need to be used together? as it may requires different  management team and expertise.

fluentd - for application log management not metrics - collects log, do transformation and ingest to various destinations

prometheus -for scraping metrics especially on container environment. Does this do application log management as well? not sure

elastricsearch - scales well for log storage & do efficient search queries.

Does I missed anything form above understanding? need your expert opinions.

Comment: This question is way to broad for SO. Also your title mentions elastic, but first sentence of body - grafana instead.

Comment: Regarding your question itself - I'm not sure on separation between fluentd/elastic, but all other - simply do different things. Prometheus - metrics: scraping and storing (no logs. direct "brother" of Prometheus for logs is Loki), Fluentd - logs, Grafana - visualization, uses data from Pormetheus and Fluentd. So those are different tools for different purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fluentd: Log collection and forwarding.

Prometheus:  Metrics collection and alerting.

Elasticsearch: Log storage, search, and visualization.

While there's an overlap, Fluentd, Prometheus, and Elasticsearch each serve different primary purposes. However, in a complex environment, especially in the context of microservices or container orchestration systems like Kubernetes, having a comprehensive view through metrics (Prometheus) and logs (Fluentd + Elasticsearch) is valuable. That said, teams should evaluate their actual needs and the associated overhead before adopting all three simultaneously.